# Symfony2 - "Warning: class_parents(): Class Ambience does not exist and could not be loaded in "

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create an entity using yml and I am getting the following error:

```
[ErrorException]

  Warning: class_parents(): Class Ambience does not exist and could not be loaded in C:\wamp\www\demo\vendor\gedmo-doctrine-extensions\lib\Gedmo\Mapping\ExtensionMetadataFactory.php line 80
```

I have created a file named **Entities.UserTestDelete.dcm.yml** in FooBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm

Contents of file:

```
Entities\UserTestDelete:
  type: entity
  table: users
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
```

Then I executed the following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "DemoFooBundle" yml
```

And then I got the error. Any idea why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem ... and managed to solve ...

a var_dump($this) on __contruct of the exception class, in my case:

- Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException

got me the $message->$trace, which led me to:

- vendor/sylius/resource-bundle/EventListener/LoadORMMetadataSubscriber.php
- calling function "class_parents"
- in function "setAssociationMappings"

So quick fix is to simply comment out the subscribed event:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
//    return array(
//        'loadClassMetadata',
//    );
}
```

now when running "app/console doctrine:mapping:import" again ... there won't be anymore errors ...

also if needed, run the mapping:convert and generate:entities command before enabling / uncommenting the subscribed Event again ...

If you are not using Sylius, try var_dump'ing on your exception class ... there's a good chance you too got some Eventlistner interfering with Doctrine's Import command ...

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

***Update***
Your first mistake is that *you* created the yml file. As explained in [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), the `doctrine:mapping:import` command actually **generates** the file. Ditch yours, run the command, and let doctrine generate the file itself.
What you do afterwards, is generate the actual entity classes:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities DemoFooBundle
```

If the tables themselves don't exist yet, then you can use these last 2 commands to generate the entities, and then run

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

To have doctrine create the tables for you.

---

A quick look in the cookbook tells me that the bundle name should not be quoted, and that you might want to pass the `--force` flag to the doctrine:mapping:import command.
[It's in the reverse-engineering bit](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force DemoFooBundle yml
```

That's the example Symfony2 cookbook gives, only changed to take yml, instead of xml format.

The error message could also be related to the table name:

```
table: users
```

Where the entity is called

```
class Users
{}
```

[possible related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413487/symfony2-class-parents-class-does-not-exist-error)

Comment: It gives the exact same error even after changing the command and changing the table name to another name.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: sorry, didn't read the question thoroughly, updated

Comment: I ditched the manually created yml file and I ran the command. It gave me the exact same error... Is there any specific config file that needs to be set for me to use doctrine?

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: Try clearing the doctrine cache (`app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` and `clear-query` and `clear-result`)

Comment: I run all three commands and they returned no results(nothing to clear). After that I ran the command and the error was still there.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: [They don't generate any output](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/Proxy/ClearMetadataCacheDoctrineCommand.php), but that doesn't mean they don't _do_ anything

Comment: sorry I edited my response. I ran the command after that regardless and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: Have a look at line 80 of the ExtensionMetadataFactory class (path is in the error message). You'll see that classes are being loaded. You must have used the Ambience class somewhere, though. Some entity is extending from it, or it is at least _mentioned_ somewhere. However, the entity does not exist. Any half-decent IDE will allow you to search an entire project for uses of a string, search your project for `Ambience`, and either define the class, or comment out the `extends` bit